# How to traverse the Drupal's watchdog table?

Tags: php, drupal, foreach, drupal-7, watchdog

I want to get all the error messages from the watchdog table, but when I get the message column from the table it has %path, %function, !message something like this messages how i can take the whole real message with not this signals?

```
<?php
  // Begin building the query.
  $query = db_select('watchdog', 'th')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->orderBy('wid')
    ->distinct()
    ->fields('th', array('variables', 'type', 'severity', 'message'))
    ->limit(2000);


  // Fetch the result set.
  $result = $query  -> execute();


  // Loop through each item and add to $row
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    blablabla($row);
  }

function blablabla($row) {   
  $severity = $row -> severity;
  $type = $row -> type;
  $message = $row -> message;
?>
```

when i use `$message` it show me something like:

```
%type: !message in %function (line %line of %file)...
```

keep in `%path`:

```
%type: !message in %function (line %line of %file)...
```

Starting to list files in `%directory`.

How i can correct this thing? Could I use an error API and how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the code below:

```
if (isset($row->message) && isset($row->variables)){
        if ($row->variables === 'N;')
          $dbmessage = $row->message;
        else $dbmessage = t($row->message, unserialize($row->variables));
          $dbmessage = filter_xss($dbmessage, array());
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started

```
blablabla($row) {
    $variables = unserialize($row->variables); // un serialize variables
    $message = t($row->message, array(
        'type'    => $row->type,
        'severity'=> $row->severity,
        // replace the rest of the variables
    ));
```

Also, check these. This is how drupal reads from watchdog table:

- [`dblog_overview`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21dblog%21dblog.admin.inc/function/dblog_overview/7); this is the function that renders this page `admin/reports/dblog`
- [`dblog_event`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21dblog%21dblog.admin.inc/function/dblog_event/7); this is the function that displays a single dblog entry inside this page `admin/reports/event/ID`.

Comment: it also shows me keep in %path or Starting to list files in %directory....it doesn't work

Comment: i put $message = theme('dblog_message', array('event' => $row)); and now it shows me the messages that has not have %file, %pathe,%line e.t.c.i do not know what to do with this problem :'(